# Cancel CTRL+C while system() is executing [C++]

Tags: c++, ctrl

How can I make CTRL+C not do anything when I'm currently doing system().

This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <signal.h>
void noCTRLCCancel(int sig) {
    signal(SIGINT, noCTRLCCancel);
    std::cout << "CTRL+C pressed, not shutting down." << std::endl;
}
inline void command() {
    system("some command"); // When CTRL+C is pressed, it cancels the command, but how to cancel CTRL+C and do nothing?
}
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    signal(SIGINT, noCTRLCCancel);
    command();
}
```

Comment: you could also properly open the process (with `popen`, `CreateProcess` or a wrapper around them). Just using `system` should be avoided if possible

Comment: I need to use it for my project, so yes, it's right that I use system()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can ignore a specific signal with SIG_IGN and set it back to default with SIG_DFL.

```
void command() {
    std::signal(SIGINT, SIG_IGN);
    system("some command");
    std::signal(SIGINT, SIG_DFL);
}
```

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/signal